# Datepicker events handler improvements issues

Tags: jquery, html

Having problems making my "events calender" from the existing datepicker in jQuery UI.

This is the code that I've come up with so far.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var myDate = new Date(dateText);
                var newFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", myDate);
                    if (newFormat === "2012-11-20") {
                        $("#div").html("KIING");
                    } else if (newFormat === "2012-11-21") {
                        $("#div").html("KIIIIIIING");
                    } else if (newFormat === "2012-11-03") {
                        $("#div").html("1234123");
                    } else {
                        $("#div").html("");
                    }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="div"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ALrkB/

I have gotten stuck here, i don't know how to make the code better and so that you don't have to insert the code manually for every event.

The thought is that the user login to the CMS and adds a query with DATE and EVENT and it connects to the jQuery code.

Comment: Sounds like a job for AJAX. When the user clicks on a date, send the date to the server, it looks it up in the DB, sends back the event name, and the Javascript puts it in the DIV.

Comment: @Barmar A simple code example and this should be the answer... not a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var ajaxCfg = {
                url: '/your/path/to/data',
                data: {selectedDate: dateText},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                  $("#div").html($(data).html());
                }
            };
            $.ajax(ajaxCfg);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="div"></div>
```

On the server side, you will need to get the post value for selectedDate and the current user, then make a query to your event database and return the data to the script.

Comment: Found a solution thx to your help there!
It had to be this, worked out nicely and clean! Thx alot!
Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/axyJz/[/link]

and the events.php ended up like this: `if (isset($_POST['selectedData'])) {
    $data = array("date" => "2012-11-20", "event" => "Meeting");
    echo json_encode($data);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jQuery code you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var myDate = new Date(dateText);
                var newFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", myDate);
                $.getJSON("callookup.php", { date: newFormat }, function(result) {
                        $("#div").html(result);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: And how would your callookup.php look like?

Comment: Writing that for him is more work than I feel like doing here. He didn't tag his question with mysql, so I'm going to assume he knows how to write a database query.